# Polymer 2 App Slow on IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, polymer

I am just about to deploy my first Polymer 2 app to production. I have to support IE 11 so I have compiled the build to the es5-bundled preset. The site seems really slow and jumpy in IE 11 (it works great in all other browsers).

Does anyone know why this is so slow in IE (other than the fact that it sucks LOL)

Here is a link to the staging server: https://davis-pwa.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: What did you investigate yourself (did you use the F12 tools for example)?